Fail to run demo Karate Gatling from GIT
I have cloned the karate demo from https://github.com/karatelabs/karate into my VScode environment.
My aim is to run karate-gatling project.
At the terminal, I run the command mvn test -P Gatling.
The test seems to start off OK but it was stopped due to below stack trace error.
The stack trace seems to suggest an issue on the class org.graalvm.polyglot.Engine$ImplHolder

What dependency I may have missed?

As mentioned in the docs, the karate-demo or karate-gatling projects are not recommended as a sample project.
For that please use the karate-todo project. Note that for Karate 1.5, there are some improvements to the Gatling part, you can use Java instead of Scala.

Thank you, I have cloned karate-todo project into VScode and run the command ./mvnw clean test => it seems to work but the process hangs at this line 12:43:27.975 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.Suite - [config] classpath:karate-config.js.  Would you be able to help me whether I miss anything?

@TonyThongsinthop that hanging sounds like the known issue with Java 22 (you most likely installed the latest Java version available) refer https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2542 - note that the second link in my answer points to a branch that uses Karate 1.5

Thank you, what version of Java should I be using?

@TonyThongsinthop 2 options - upgrade to Karate 1.5.0.RC4 or use a version of Java less than 22
